# Incorrect timezone in Firefox, compared to Safari, using javascript Date()

Tags: javascript, firefox, timezone

The following code

```
var date = new Date();
console.log( date );
```

gives me

```
Sun Mar 06 2011 21:41:36 GMT+1300 (NZST) {}
```

in Firefox, but

```
Sun Mar 06 2011 21:40:51 GMT+1300 (NZDT)
```

in Safari (which is correct).

My system Date & Time is set to NZDT, so I'm wondering where firefox is getting its NZST from. Mind you, the UTC offset (+1300) is correct in both cases.

How can I get Firefox displaying the correct timezone: NZDT?

Comment: Looks like a labeling error, albeit a very annoying one

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed in Firefox 4; I get the incorrect timezone in 3.6, but not in 4.0 beta 12.

Comment: You should really be using jquery are you wouldn't get this error

Comment: @Carnotaurus: I do use jQuery, but not for dates. How would using it stop this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in Firefox v4 and later.

Comment: I'm rephrasing another comment in the form of a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on that output as it's different in other browsers (IE), instead you should use the getTimezoneOffset method.

```
var date = new Date;
console.log( date.getTimezoneOffset() );
```

The offset will change with day light savings but there are ways to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is how you want it except for the "NZST", you could just do a simple text replace:

```
console.log(date.toString().replace('NZST', 'NZDT'));
```

Note that this is really only simple fix for the display issue, it doesn't address the underlying cause.

Comment: And it would be incorrect during the time of year when New Zealand is actually on NZST.